# HTML5 canvasで、テキストではなく、リンクテキストを描画したい

Tags: html5-canvas

**現状**
・テキストなので、リンクを読み込むと、そのまま表示されてしまいます

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasのID名');  
ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
```

出力結果

```
<a href="/">スタック・オーバーフロー</a>
```

---

**質問**
・aタグを(リンク機能を保持したまま)canvasへ描画するためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
※描画後、canvas機能でアニメーション表示させる予定

Comment: 要素を`canvas`に描画するのではなく、`position: absolute`で上に重ねるべきではないでしょうか

Comment: 画像内にどうしても埋め込みたいなら、canvasの画像をimgに突っ込んでclickable mapを作成するのでは駄目ですか？

Comment: 「上に重ねるべき」の意味が分からないのですが、HTML要素(aタグ)はcanvasへ描画出来ないのでしょうか？　また、clickable mapでは都合が悪いです。 aタグを、fillTextで描画した時のように、canvas要素として操作したいので…

Comment: @re9 もちろん`canvas`に`a`要素の`textContent`を描画したりマウスイベントを拾って様々な処理を行うことは可能です。しかし`a`の持つ疑似クラスやタイトル、さらにはコンテキストメニューやアクセシビリティなどを考えると`canvas`に描画したうえでエミュレートするよりも、実際の`a`要素として`canvas`に重ねて表示した方が簡潔で機能性も高くなるのではないかと思います。

Comment: canvasはただのビットマップ画像なので、描画した図形やテキストをリンクにするというのはできません。これに対してSVGであれば描画した要素を個別に認識できるので、イベントを拾ったり個別にアニメーションしたりもできます。`<a>`要素も使えるのでリンクを埋め込む事もできます。もし他の要件を満たせるようであれば、SVGに置き換える事を検討してみては如何でしょうか。

Comment: @pgrho　canvasにHTMLを重ねて表示するケースを見かけるのですが、そういう意図なのですね

Comment: @tag1216　canvas標準機能としては無理なんですね。初めて知りました。また、SVG‌​であれば<a>要素も使えるんですね。アドバイスありがとうございました。検討してみたいと思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

望んでいることは出来ないんじゃないか？……と思って調べてみました。
[本家SOの方に同じ質問をしている方がいた](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215841)のでリンクしておきます。

要するに実現している内容はclickable mapと同じです。
キャンバスの上に動いているマウスの座標を取得して、
指定座標内でクリックされたら遷移するものです。

WEB以外の表示でリンクしたい……は出来ません。
結局、出力は画像なので、出力する画像フォーマットにリンクの機能がないとリンクは出来ないです。

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx;
        var linkText = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        var linkX = 5;
        var linkY = 15;
        var linkHeight = 10;
        var linkWidth;
        var inLink = false;

        // draw the balls on the canvas
        function draw() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            // check if supported
            if (canvas.getContext) {

                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                //clear canvas
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                //draw the link
                ctx.font = '10px sans-serif';
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
                ctx.fillText(linkText, linkX, linkY);
                linkWidth = ctx.measureText(linkText).width;

                //add mouse listeners
                canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
                canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);

            }
        }

        //check if the mouse is over the link and change cursor style
        function on_mousemove(ev) {
            var x, y;

            // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
            if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { //for firefox
                x = ev.layerX;
                y = ev.layerY;
            }
            x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
            y -= canvas.offsetTop;

            //is the mouse over the link?
            if (x >= linkX && x <= (linkX + linkWidth) && y <= linkY && y >= (linkY - linkHeight)) {
                document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
                inLink = true;
            }
            else {
                document.body.style.cursor = "";
                inLink = false;
            }
        }

        //if the link has been clicked, go to link
        function on_click(e) {
            if (inLink) {
                window.location = linkText;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
    <center>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px">Canvas not supported.</canvas>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 「キャンバスの上に動いているマウスの座標を取得して、指定座標内でクリックされたら遷移する」って方法しかないんですね。リンク提示ありがとうございました。参考になりました